# Remove sub directory and id from the url Address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently my urls are:

http://welcome.something.com/task/demo-log.php?id=worklog

http://welcome.something.com/task/demo-team.php?id=team

I have similar multiple url.

Till 
http://welcome.something.com/task/demo- everthing is same. I have created htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*/|)(?:demo-log\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)([^/]*)$ $1demo-log.php?id=$2 [L]
```

with the help of current htacess code I am able to get this

http://welcome.something.com/task/worklog

Now I want to remove **task** subdirectory (like this http://welcome.something.com/worklog) and ..apply this url rule to all my files like

http://welcome.something.com/task/demo-team.php?id=team   to be changed to

http://welcome.something.com/team